# Rotation of the window not the ViewController

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, window, rotation

First of all i am a n00b. After long time of trying and research i decided to get some external help.
My Project:
i made a book for children, but it was rejected because it only allowed portrait orientation.
it seams apple wants upside-down as well.
in my appdelegate i switch the ViewControllers (Pages of my Book), there the rotation works.
But behind the Pages i have the window from my appdelegate, the pages are rotating but not my window/background.
How and where in my delegate can i (allow) rotate my window in portrait and upside-down?
Here my appdelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions    
{    

UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t2.jpg"];
UIImageView *tisch = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
tisch.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
[window addSubview:tisch];
[tisch release];

[self addButtonNext];
[self initAnimation];
[self animieren:self.animation];
[self playNavigation];
[self addButtonStop];
[self addButtonPlay];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Any ideas?
It would be really cool if anyone could help me! 
Thanks in advance Planky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you say "it seams apple wants upside-down as well" this is very surprising. Most iOS applications explicitly do not support upside-down orientation since it is often a poor user experience. They only support portrait and left/right landscape.

Next, do not add subviews directly to the win`dow`. This is almost always wrong and bypasses the built-in rotation logic (as you've discovered). Just use a `UIViewController`. That's what it's for. You can (though you generally shouldn't) add things to the `window.rootViewController.view`, but this is really only for specialized problems (like drag-and-drop across peer views). Just use a view controller. It will solve 90% of your problems out of the box.

Rather than having a single view controller per page, just have a single PageViewController that changes which Page it displays. The PageViewController can then put all these extra UI elements into the view.

Comment: thanks for you time. 
i made a viewcontroller for switching the Pages.
window can't handle rotation.
The GUI-Guidelines for iPad require upside-down.